# Heap vs binary search tree (when it is better than the other?)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-search-tree

In what situations is using a min-heap more efficient than using a binary search tree? Is it true that the time of finding the minimum in a binary search tree is equal to finding minimum value in min-heap - O(1)?

Comment: Which data structure is best will depend a lot on the specific situation in which you are using it. Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or is this a general question?

Answer (score 5):

This is almost like comparing coffee cups and koala bears. Heaps and binary search trees are intended to perform very different functions. A heap is an implementation of the priority queue abstract data type. At the basic level, a priority queue (and thus a heap) is just a bag where you put things, and when you reach in to get an item out you always get the smallest (min-heap) or largest (max-heap) item in the bag.

You can get fancy and give your heap the ability to remove any arbitrary item, or to change the priority of an item in the heap, but those are more advanced functionality and don't fall within the bounds of the traditional definition of the heap data structure.

A binary search tree is a much different beast. It's a bag where you put things, and you can quickly reach in to grab any item by key or you can list all of the items in order (or reverse order).

You can use a binary search tree to implement a priority queue, meaning that you could in principle replace a heap with a binary tree. The binary search tree wouldn't perform as well as the heap, but it would get the job done.

But the reverse isn't true. You can't use a heap to replace a binary search tree.

So the question of which is better is really a question of what do you want to do?

If you want an ordered set of items from which you can quickly locate any item, or that you can traverse in order, then you want a binary search tree.

If you want an implementation of the priority queue abstract data type: a bag that will quickly give you the smallest (or largest, depending on how you define it) item when you ask for it, then you want to use a heap.

Answer (score 2):

The two have different uses and are not interchangeable.

**A heap** is a structure that guarantees you that the value of a given node is lower or equal (for a min heap; greater or equal for a max heap) than the value of any node underneath. This allows to get the minimum (or maximum) value in *O(1)*.

**A binary search tree** is a structure that keeps all nodes ordered. This allows to retrieve any value in *O(h)* (*h* being the height of the tree, and *h=log<sub>2</sub>(n)* if the tree is balanced, with *n* the number of nodes).

Comment: The height of a balanced binary search tree is log(n) (specifically log base 2), not *ln*, which is the *natural logarithm, base e*.

Comment: @MillieSmith, very true, but that will not affect the big-O access time, since any logarithm base is just a constant factor off any other.

Comment: @dfeuer, That's true, but it's still misleading (and incorrect). The order is the same, but the height *!=* ln(n).

Comment: @JulienGuertault I think the better way to implement a build system would be to make a dependency graph (objects = nodes, dependencies = edges).  Then, you would do a topological sort of the graph.  This not only runs faster (O(n) time), but it also makes more sense because you don't know how to compare two objects and determine which should be built before the other without following the entire dependency chain.